# ChatJS how can I only have private chat without room?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, chatjs

I am using ChatJS: http://www.chatjs.net/

for chatting in my web app. The chat should be only private. I don't want any room selection. I want to list all friends in the panel and then they could chat among themselves. I don't want any group chat either since the chat has to be private. Is this possible in chatjs?

The options page suggests to specify `room Id` and `allowRoomSelection`. But when this parameter to false and roomId to 1 nothing happens.

Please suggest what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, the ability to not show chat rooms, and simply show a list of users as you see in Facebook is being implemented yet. I'll let you know and update this asnwer once it's finished.

Comment: Andre, if you were to make it so that ChatJS could work like Facebook for person to person chat and integrate it with ASP.NET Identity (users and roles) for security, ChatJS will explode in popularity.   Its already very cool and you have done a great job.